# How can I translate pool to Spanish

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, informática

I'm translating strings of a open source project (virt-manager). I need to translate the word '**pool**' with the meaning of (i.e.) a **set of** devices.
Piscina, estanque, charca, consorcio, pileta and other words has nothing to do with this meaning. What's the word I'm looking for?

Comment: Set: conjunto.  Grupo, perhaps.  Collección.  Linguee is a great resource for this sort of thing.  http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that the word you are using is:

> **conjunto**: totalidad de los elementos que tienen una característica o propiedad que los distingue de otros.

The search of pool on a non-technical dictionary will give you translations like the ones you listed and and no one of them are close to the meaning. Looking for set would probably give you the right one.

But, as other users said, in this context you can use the English term without confusion.

Comment: This answer could benefit of explaining why do think "conjunto" is the best choice (what does it mean? why do you think it is the best choice for this particular case?). I mean, I could say "the word you are looking for is _(this other one)_" and other users will upvote or downvote but there is nothing like you explaining your thought in the post.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is the first time I post in stackexchange. I will follow your feedback from now on.

Comment: As with so many other IT terms, I object to translating this because it can cause confusion. *Conjunto* is a usual translation for *set*, which in computing is a completely different concept.

Comment: What word would you use? Just pool?

Answer (score 2):

Como bien dice @pablopez buscar en un diccionario **no técnico** ofrece más problemas que soluciones.

El significado de *pool* es el de una combinación de recursos independientes en un único grupo lógico, por lo que traducciones como **grupo o conjunto** serían totalmente válidas para su uso informático.

Si quieres un [glosario técnico centrado en la informática](http://www.tugurium.com/gti/) te ofrezco el del enlace (espero no haber violado alguna regla de este sitio por enviarte a mi glosario).